# How to find time differences in diagonally opposite excel cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
     a      b      c       d    Time spent
1   CUS1    pc  10:05   10:15   
2   CUS1    pf  11:00   11:10   
3   CUS1    pm  12:00   12:10   
4   CUS1    pw  13:00   13:10   
5   CUS2    pc  10:24   10:34   
6   CUS2    pf  11:05   11:15   
7   CUS2    pm  11:45   11:55   
8   CUS2    pw  12:27   12:37
```

Above are the times spend by each customer (col a) on 4 different products assigned to them. The times spent are captured and I need to make sure they waited 30mins or more before starting to spend time on new product.  Basically, for cus1 the difference between cells c2 and d1 and c3 and d2 and c4 and d3  and carry on the same pattern for all cells below. 
I am new to advanced excel  but heard of excel matrices etc, but not sure what logical set up I need to use to make this work. I am willing to learn any direction offered or if there is a direct way to approach this. 
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write this formula at `E2` and fill down:

```
=IF(A2=A1, (C2-D1)*24*60, "")
```

This will display the difference in minutes. After that, you can use *conditional formatting* to highlight the cells of column E that are less than 30 minutes.

Comment: Thanks very much. Got some leads into doing similar tasks. :-)